# Simple probability question - Calculating Possible Outcomes

Tags: probability

I am reading through probability book - Introduction to Probability by Joseph K. Blitzstein (Author) and Jessica Hwang (Author). The book is available online here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/view

There is an example - "Suppose you are buying an ice cream cone. You can choose whether to have a cake cone or waffle cone, and whether to have chocolate, vanilla, or strawberry as your flavor."

Different possibilities for one scoop of ice cream is deduced by a simple tree diagram, which is 6 possibilities.

The example further expands - Now suppose you buy two ice cream cones on a certain day, one in afternoon and the other in the evening. By multiplication rule, there are 6<sup>2</sup> possibilities for the compound experiment.

I am not sure how 6<sup>2</sup> is valid here. I further extended my tree diagram to visualize the same and I am ending with 12 possible branches. I am confused as to what am I missing here.

PS: Example is on Page 10 and 11 of the book.

Comment: Imagine you buy a waffle cone with strawberry flavor in the afternoon. In the evening, you have 6 possible alternatives to pair up with your afternoon choice. Now, in the afternoon you also have 6 possible choices, and for each of this choices you can have 6 alternative evening pairings. Total number of pairings is 36.

Comment: Thank You @Evgeny. I was missing the pairing of 6 possible options from the afternoon with another potential 6 pairing options in the evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to visualize the two-cone situation as a single tree might not be the best way to go about this. That said, the two-cone tree is the one-cone tree with another copy of the one-cone tree descending from *every* leaf. It sounds like instead of that you might have two copies of the one-cone tree next to each other (perhaps descending from a common parent).

No matter which of the 6 possibilities you chose in the afternoon, you go through the *same* decision tree again in the evening. For each of the 6 afternoon possibilities, there are another 6 possible choices in the evening, for a total of $6\cdot6=6^2$ possibilities for the two cones.

Comment: The way I was visualizing the whole thing was totally wrong. I did not compound the afternoon and evening possibilities correctly!